# Programatically design chess board cubes in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and am trying to create the chess board background in unity. I need the scene to be full of cubes using the prefab I created. When the counter is even, the cube is set to black else to red. I don't know what is going on really because nothing is showing up when z is 0. This is my code..

```
public GameObject pre;

    public int counter = 0;
    public int worldWidth = 20;
    public int worldHeight = 20;

    private float positionX;
    private float positionY;

    void Start()
    {
        chessBoardCube = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/pre");
        positionX = -11.24f;
        positionY = 4.8f;
        counter = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < worldHeight; z++)
            {
                if (counter % 2 == 0)
                {
                    GameObject block = Instantiate(pre, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    block.renderer.material.color = Color.black;
                    block.transform.parent = transform;
                    float xP = positionX * 3;
                    float yP = positionY * z;

                    block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 1);
                    block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xP, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    GameObject block = Instantiate(pre, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    block.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
                    block.transform.parent = transform;
                    float xP = positionX * x;
                    float yP = positionY * z;
                    block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 1);
                    block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xP, 0);
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

The positionX and positionY variables are the position that the prefab is set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `I don't know what is going on really because nothing is showing up when z is 0.` What does that mean? Are your prefabs being instantiated?

Comment: Yes they area. But when z is 0, the prefabs are not shown on the screen but I can see that they are instantiated in the Hierarchy section.

Comment: Double click 1 clone prefab and see where it is being instantiated. Then make corrections to positioning and rotation to put it where you want.

Comment: But can you tell me what I need to do to have one next to each other?

Comment: z iterates from 0 to 19. "Nothing is showing up when z is 0" means that only one row is missing?

Comment: No, literally nothing is showing up. Just the prefab on the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
    public GameObject pre;

    public int worldWidth = 20;
    public int worldHeight = 20;

    public float cubeSize = 2;

    private float positionX;
    private float positionY;
    private float positionZ;

    void Start()
    {
        chessBoardCube = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/pre");
        positionX = -11.24f;
        positionY = 4.8f;
        positionZ = 0.0f;
    }

    //Probably unwanted in update
    void Update()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < worldHeight; y++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(pre, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;

                if(x%2 == 0) {
                    if(y%2 == 0) {
                        block.renderer.material.color = Color.black;
                    } else {
                        block.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(y%2 == 0) {
                        block.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
                    } else {
                        block.renderer.material.color = Color.black;
                    }
                }

                float xP = positionX + x*cubeSize;
                float yP = positionY + y*cubeSize;

                block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(cubeSize, cubeSize, 1);
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xP, yP, positionZ);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Max, first of all thanks for your help. But once again nothing is showing on the screen. I can see that the instantiations are being done but are not shown on the screen.

Comment: When I switch to scene view and zoom out, I can see that the grid is being generated. How can I put it so that I can see it in the screen of the game view?

Comment: You should place the camera in right position. Find gameobject with attached camera in the hierarchy, go to scene view and place this gameobject to observe the whole grid. Camera viewport will be shown in scene view when camera object is selected.

Comment: Btw, I thought that positionX and positionY are the proper shifts to get into your camera view. Probably you don't need them at all. Also you probably don't want to instantiate 400 cubes every frame in Update, unless it's some kind of stress test.

Comment: I'm trying to place it in the right position but still can't get it to show on the screen. sorry but I'm new to Unity.

Comment: Check the z axis on your camera and ensure that it isn't so close to your gameobjects that it clips them out

Comment: Set positionX and positionY to zero, set position and rotation of gameobject with this script (parent transform) to (0,0,0) and scale to (1,1,1), set camera rotation to (0,0,0) and position to (20,20,-40), thus you should see at least something.

Answer (score -1):

```
void generateBoard(){
        float tempX = cubePrefab.transform.localScale.x;
        float tempY = cubePrefab.transform.localScale.y;
        float tempZ = cubePrefab.transform.localScale.z;

        for (int i = 0; i < boardLength; i++) {
            tempX = cubePrefab.transform.localScale.x;

            for (int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(cubePrefab, parentTransform) as GameObject;
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(tempX , tempY , tempZ);
                tempX += cubePrefab.transform.localScale.x;

                if(i%2 == 0){
                    if(j%2 == 0){
                        block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
                    }else{
                        block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(j%2 == 0){
                        block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
                    }else{
                        block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
                    }
                }
            }

            tempZ += cubePrefab.transform.localScale.z;
        }
    }
```